# How to pass info from SAML response received in Web API to Angular App and load page

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

I have implemented SAML support to the backend which is a WebAPI after OKTA authentication.

Now problem is how to establish connection with AngularJS app when the triggering point is browser which directly send response to a WebAPI Action.

Basically, I have to pass info from WebAPI action (Action not triggered by AngularJS app but by browser directly after receiving response) to the AngualrJS front end and load a page with that info.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the SAMLToken in the querystring to your javascript application. And make sure that your server allow max query string.

[Standard Practice](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/saml-for-your-serverless-javascript-application-part-i/)